# How can I use fuzzy matching to remove part of string?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

Our system currently produced duplicated content in customers' address field. For example:

Currently it presents like:

> No.123 Collingwood Road, Colchester, Essex, United Kingdom

And the target content should be:

> No.123 Collingwood Road

As the part needs to be reomoved, which is "Colchester, Essex, United Kingdom" are various, so SQL statement as below would not work:

```
update bi_person_info
set hrhouse_number= REPLACE(hrhouse_number,'Colchester, Essex, United Kingdom','')
where input_organ_code='456151384' or INPUT_CENTER_ORGAN_CODE='456151384';
```

Therefore the fuzzy matching method is required in this case, strings in this field start with "Colchester" and ends with "Kingdom" all need to be removed. The content between the two key words are various, but the two key words are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything up to the first comma, you could use:

```
select regexp_substr(address, '^[^,]+')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25fd3676a24acb10335a247a1c1ba288) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  There are other ways to take all the characters up to the first comma.  However, you may want more control over the exact logic and regular expressions are quite powerful.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did try regular expression, but eventually I found another way: 
                                                                                                                                      
update bi_person_info
set hrhouse_number=replace(hrhouse_number,hrhouse_number,
    substr(hrhouse_number, instr(hrhouse_number,'Kingdom')+7)
)
where idcard in ('320581199010042417','441802201911240129') and hrhouse_number like 'Colchester%Kingdom%';